# why am I getting a none being printed after my display function?

Tags: python

I am getting a none by the end og my display function, doe anyone know what i am doing wrong?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'anonymous'
        self.birth = 'unknown'

    def displayPerson(self):
        print('{} (b. {})'.format(self.name, self.birth))

class Book(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bookName = 'untitled'
        self.author = Person()
        self.published = 'unpublished'


    def displayBook(self):
        print(self.bookName)
        print('Publisher:')
        print(self.published)
        print('Author:')
        print(self.author.displayPerson())

def main():

    newBook = Book()
    newBook.displayBook()

    print('')
    print ('Please enter the following: ')
    newBook.author.name = input('Name: ')
    newBook.author.birth = input('Year: ')
    newBook.bookName = input('Title: ')
    newBook.published = input('Publisher: ')
    print('')

    newBook.displayBook()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `displayBook` method, You write:

`print(self.author.displayPerson())`

The call to the other method prints the desired output, and then `self.author.displayPerson()` returns a None (in Python, all functions have a return. Those that don't explicitly return a value return a None instead). However, you then call a `print` on that output, thus you see the extra None.

So, either use:

```
def displayBook(self):
    print(self.bookName)
    print('Publisher:')
    print(self.published)
    print('Author:')
    self.author.displayPerson() #No print needed, since the method call itself has a print
```

Or alternatively, don't use a `print` in `displayPerson`, but have it return the string. Then print inside `displaybook` as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You return a print sentence in another print sentence

The solution can to be (Same, but without the 'print' word):

```
def displayPerson(self):
    return ('{} (b. {})'.format(self.name, self.birth))
```